# How to locate the grandparent of elements using Selenium (Python) in a loop

Tags: selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, xpath, ancestor

I am trying to append the name of a value which it's child element is less then 120.

My code is

```
list = []
rate = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="sFive"]')
for e in rate:
    if int(e.text) < 120:
        title=e.find_element(By.XPATH, x).text #find ancestor element
        list.append(title)

print(list)
```

The x is where I need to find the grandparent which is the 21st span element up that branch.

The span element is

```
<span data-slnm="Brand" class="ng-star-inserted">Inter</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The target element being:

```
<span data-slnm="Brand" class="ng-star-inserted">Inter</span>
```

To locate the element which is the 21<sup>st</sup> grandparent `<span>` element up that branch you can use the either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Identifying the 21st `<span>` ancestor:

  ```
  list = []
  rate = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="sFive"]')
  for e in rate:
      if int(e.text) < 120:
      title = e.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="sFive"]//ancestor::span[21]').text
      list.append(title)
  print(list)
  ```
- Identifying the specific `<span>` ancestor:

  ```
  list = []
  rate = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="sFive"]')
  for e in rate:
      if int(e.text) < 120:
      title = e.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="sFive"]//ancestor::span[@class="ng-star-inserted" and @data-slnm="Brand"]').text
      list.append(title)
  print(list)
  ```

Comment: Tried by identifying the specific <span> ancestor, but it throw an error NoSuchElementException. Do I need maybe to locate the <span> parent <div> which is <div class="InfoSummary"> and then locate the <span>? Do you know how should I go about it? Also, why we need to add //span[@class="sFive"] again in the e.find_element if it was already found in the rate variable? Thanks!

Comment: Its my first time dealing with ancestors but I would add here that the <span> is not a direct ancestor but there are many branches that descends from on main <div class=d-sm-flex justify-content-between> before splitting into different branches. Does this fact change anything?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.